Can Sloppy Quorum guarantee strong read consistency?
In the book "Designing Data-Intensive Applications. The Big Ideas Behind Reliable, Scalable and Maintainable Systems", we can read regarding Sloppy Quorum :

However, this means that even when w + r > n, you cannot be sure to read the latest value for a key, because the latest value may have been temporarily written to some nodes outside of n

But i can't seem to understand the meaning behind this.
Let's take an example of clients writing different values for a key "K1".
Suppose we have :

Number of replicas : N=3
Number of acknowledgement before a write is considered successful : W=2
Number of responses before a read is considered successful : R=2
Available Nodes : A, B, C, D, and E

We have W+R>N.
Suppose we already have a first value for "K1" in A, B, and C : (K1,V1)
Then suppose nodes A and B fail, then a client writes (K1,V2) in a Sloppy Quorum configuration.
My understanding is that we will use nodes C, D, and E to write and replicate (K1, V2) in order to avoid blocking the write operation like in a Strict Quorum configuration, and we need the acknowledgment of two of these nodes. Let's say we received acknowledgements from C and D, so the write is successfull.
Now another client wants to read the value of K1, its need two responses, and we have three possibilities :

C and D respond first : we are sure to get (K1, V2) because these are the nodes that aknowledged the write of (K1,V2)
C and E respond first : we might either get two (K1, V2), or a (K1, V2) from C and a (K1, V1) from E if replication to E did not finish yet. In the latter case it is still possible to resolve the conflict using versionning algorithms like Vector Clock. So as long as our system is able to resolve conflicts we are sure to get (K1, V2) (also, such conflict can also happen in a Strict Quorum configuration so it is not really due to the Sloppy Quorum configuration in our case)
D and E respond first : same as the above (i.e. C and E case)

So from this, i would say that our Sloppy Quorum system can guarantee strong read consistency (as long as it handles conflicts, which again is also something that should be handled in Strict Quorum configurations) since the returned value would be (K1,V2), which is not what seems to be explained in the book.
Is there anything wrong in this reasoning ?
Edit 31/12/2024: After reading the question months later, i might want to replace "Then suppose nodes A and B fail, then a client writes (K1,V2) in a Sloppy Quorum configuration" with "Then suppose nodes A and B fail, then (K1,V1) is replicated from C to D and E (since N=3), then a client writes (K1,V2) in a Sloppy Quorum configuration", so that it is clear why E might later respond with (K1,V1).

Since this is a conceptial question and not one about some specific code that was displayed that needs to be fixed, this is probably the wrong stack for this type of question unfortunately.  If you are fortunate a mod will move it, if you are unfortunate they won't and the question will get downvotes and hurt your account :(

Thanks for the advice, i've seen many similar questions in SO, so i think it should be fine. I'll just let it as it is for people looking for an answer here.

After some research and analysis, i think i managed to understand what the author meant.
The reasoning in the question is correct, but incomplete :
After the second client gets the value (K1,V2), suppose nodes A and B are restored.
Normally, since we are in a Sloppy Quorum configuration, there will be a Hinted Handoff phase where nodes D and E send recent data back to A and B when these are restored. We can read in the book :

Once the network interruption is fixed, any writes that one node
temporarily accepted on behalf of another node are sent to the
appropriate “home” nodes. This is called hinted handoff.

The problem with our Sloppy Quorum configuration is that, if another client wants to read the value of K1 right after nodes A and B are restored, but before Hinted Handoff has started, it is possible that this client gets two responses from A and B with the old value (K1,V1), and the client will accept this value since R=2. So the client will not get the latest value in this case, just as explained in the book.
Clients can safely get the latest value (K1, V2) only after Hinted Handoff has completed as explained by the author :

Thus, a sloppy quorum actually isn’t a quorum at all in the
traditional sense. It’s only an assurance of durability, namely that
the data is stored on w nodes somewhere. There is no guarantee that a
read of r nodes will see it until the hinted handoff has completed.

So the answer to the question "Can Sloppy Quorum guarantee strong read consistency?" would be : No.

Nice answer. However I dont get the meaning of non - home nodes. Are they kind of backup nodes which are responsible for keeping data in case quorum is not available or they could just nodes which are responsible to keep data of different partition. In case of partition does w,r signifies number of leaderless nodes available per parition?  Sorry I just have too many questions.

Thanks for the feedback! non-home nodes for a given partition are nodes which are not among the N nodes initially chosen to store and replicate the data of that given partition, but which may be used to store data of that given partition in case of failure of some of the N home nodes. In Consistent Hashing for example, the non-home nodes would be just nodes that normally store data of other partitions (refer to chapter 6 of "System Design Interview – An insider's guide" by Xu Alex).

When we want to write/read some data belonging to a given partition, W/R refer to the number of acknowledgements/reponses needed from nodes that store data of that given partition, and which could be home nodes or non-home nodes (knowing that N is the total number of nodes that store data of that given partition, so W<=N and R<=N).

Sloppy Quorum is not explicitly defined in Designing Data-Intensive Applications, but you will find a hint in this sentence:

Writes and reads still require w and r successful responses, but those may include nodes that are not among the designated n home nodes for a value [p. 183, emphasis added]

Illustration, row 1
In essence, the key space is partitioned, that is, keys do not get replicated to all nodes but a subset of nodes.
Illustration, row 2
If some nodes of the quorum for a key are not available, the key value will be written to other nodes with a hinted handoff.
Illustration, row 3
When the nodes become available, the correctness condition w + r > n will (temporarily) be violated.
Illustration, row 4
Eventually, the key value will be updated.

Edit
I just realized I missed your answer while drafting and submitting mine. Apologies for the redundancy.

Thanks, much clearer with the illustration ! In my understanding however, "w + r > n" will never be violated, and this is not necesseraly contradictory to the first sentence you mentionned : "those may include nodes that are not among the designated n home nodes". In row 2, we can see that nodes D and E that are not among the n home nodes (i.e. A, B, C) do handle the write request. And for me, in row 3,  "w + r > n" is not violated, we still have N=3, the difference with row 2 is just that every read or write request will be now redirected again to A, B, and C, and not to D and E anymore.
